# YTD unique number of users per month

Tags: sql

I need to calculate YTD unique number of users per month.I am currently struggling with writing the logic for that. I found the solution for values where you don't need to count unique , but in this case it makes things a bit more complicated.
So for example if I have 4 users A,B,C,D and they are showing like this:

```
Date          User id
============
2019/01/06    A
-------------
2019/01/25    B
-------------
2019/02/05    C
-------------
2019/02/05    A
------------
2019/03/05    C
-------------
2019/04/05    D
-------------
```

My output should be like this (so for example for March, having unique number of users showing from January to the end of March)

```
MONTH   user count
=================
January  2
-----------------
February 3
-----------------
March    3
-----------------
April    4
------------------
```

Is there some simple solution for this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, would you please provide your query?

Comment: ... because when it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
DECLARE  @Table TABLE(date date , UserID varchar(250))

INSERT INTO @table values
('2019/01/06', 'A'),
('2019/01/25', 'B'),
('2019/02/05', 'C'),
('2019/02/05', 'A'),
('2019/03/05', 'C'),
('2019/04/05', 'D')


SELECT DISTINCT
   DATENAME(MONTH, Date) [Date], --This function returns a character string representing the specified datepart of the specified date.
   Count(UserID) [UserIDSum] -- it counts the amount of UserIds
FROM @Table GROUP BY Date
```

DATENAME's function [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Data ouput:**

```
Date     | UserIDSum
--------------------
April    | 1
February | 2
January  | 1
March    | 1
```

At least this works for MSSSQL. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Fmanin, OP need the cumulative sum not only sum. Such as for January its 2, for Feb its 3, for March its 3 and for April its 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can count a user in the first month s/he appears:

```
select year(min_date), month(min_date),
       count(*) as starts_in_month,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(min_date)
from (select user_id, min(date) as min_date
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) u
group by year(min_date), month(min_date)
order by year(min_date), month(min_date);
```

Note that date functions vary by database.  You should be able to extract the year and month using some construct like this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query,

```
 create table #tempt(tdate datetime, userid varchar(20));
 insert into #tempt (tdate, userid) values('2019-02-06','A');
 insert into #tempt (tdate, userid) values('2019-01-06','A');
 insert into #tempt (tdate, userid) values('2019-01-06','B');
 select * from #tempt

 select  FORMAT(tdate, 'MMMM')as Monthname, count(userid)as usercount from #tempt 
 group by tdate
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
 declare @Table table (tdate datetime, userid varchar(20));
 insert into @Table (tdate, userid) values('2019-01-06','A');
 insert into @Table (tdate, userid) values('2019-02-06','D');
 insert into @Table (tdate, userid) values('2019-02-06','C');
 insert into @Table (tdate, userid) values('2019-02-06','A');
 insert into @Table (tdate, userid) values('2019-03-06','B');
 insert into @Table (tdate, userid) values('2019-04-06','D');
 insert into @Table (tdate, userid) values('2019-05-06','E');

; with cte as (
    select tdate, userid, year(tdate) as yr , month(tdate) as mon from @Table
 ) 
 , ct as 
 (
    select distinct c.yr, c.mon, ct.userid as cc from cte as c 
    cross join cte as ct where c.tdate>=ct.tdate
    group by c.yr, c.mon, ct.userid
  )
  select distinct yr, mon, count(cc) from ct group by yr, mon
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.